# Javascript Regex content file to show as table

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, readfile

I have a file with content as below:

```
[10:46:43] Info of person (username(294) - System ID:106400 - Tag:sachotta) Additional data: N/D
[00] - PersonAccessory: "/structA/structB/structC/structD/data.txt"
[01] - PersonAccessory: "/structA/structB/structC/structD/general.txt"
[02] - PersonAccessory: "/structA/structB/structC/structD/d16g750.txt"
------------End------------
[23:58:08] Spawning GameTruck (sebestyenfarago(ABC)(109) - System ID:886375 - Tag:Szemerey GMBH.) Additional data: N/D
[00] - PersonAccessory: "/struct1/struct2/struct3/struct4/data.txt"
[01] - PersonAccessory: "/struct1/struct2/struct3/struct4/general.txt"
[02] - PersonAccessory: "/struct1/struct2/struct3/struct4/dg1651s.txt"
------------End------------
```

I want to show content of file to table:

```
+----+----------+----+--------+--------+--------+
| No.| username | ID | Sys ID |   Tag  | Struct |
+----+----------+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 01 |username  |294 | 106400 |sachotta| structD|
+----+----------+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 02 |sebestyen |109 | 886375 |Szemerey| struct4|
+----+----------+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

My code here: http://codepen.io/nphunghung/pen/jrbjLQ
And my file using to read: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzvYy1AQW5f-U0FLM2FheVpCOHM

But why my regex is false. Please help me check it.

Thanks you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Have you even tried to build a regex before asking here?

Comment: I understand it. I have try to code. This's my code to read file and show content: http://codepen.io/nphunghung/pen/jrbjLQ
In this, I using Regex to filter the content. But it's false??? Why that. While, I tested my regex here: https://regex101.com/r/iB2bO7/1, it's true.
This file I using to read: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzvYy1AQW5f-U0FLM2FheVpCOHM

Comment: regex is for reading data, not displaying it

Comment: @deltree: I'm using regex to check condition, if it true will be display my content. Can you check my code here: http://codepen.io/nphunghung/pen/jrbjLQ

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if this is what you need, but you can try to read data with regex:

```
^\[\d+:\d+:\d+\][^(]+\(([^)]+)\)[^:]+:(\d+)\s+-\s+Tag:(\w+)(?:(?:.|\W)(?!\w+\/\w+\.txt))*\/(\w+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nE4lZ0/3)

It match:

- `^\[\d+:\d+:\d+\][^(]+\(` - start on a beginning of a line(`^`), and match a
  fragment up to username part,
- `([^)]+)` - $1 group, match    username (any char but not `)` to
  match everything in parathesis),
- `\)[^:]+:` - fragment up to id number - closing bracket, followed by one or more chars that are not colon, then followed by colon;
- `(\d+)` - $2 group, matching id number - one or more digit
- `\s+-\s+Tag:` - matching up to tag part - one or more whitespace, hyphen, one or more whitespace followed by 'Tag' word,
- `(\w+)` - $3 group, matching tag - one or more alphanumeric char
- `(?:(?:.|\W)(?!\w+\/\w+\.txt))*\/` - match any character not followed
  by fragment in format: */anyword/anyword.txt*,
- `(\w+)` - $4 group, matching *structureX* fragment;

Assuming that whole file is formatted this way, you can extract values, and then format string as you like.

Comment: That's a really nasty regular expression to post with no explanation what-so-ever. Can you imagine coming back to this in 6 months time because there's a bug in it and trying to locate it?

Comment: @Thor84no you are absolutely right, I will change that, thank you for comment

Comment: That's much better. Thanks! I'd still hope for a non-regex solution, but this would at least help OP understand and potentially maintain it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote code regex but not as professional as you: regex101.com/r/iB2bO7/1 . But when check in regex101, it's true, and when using it with javascript code to check condition, result is false.
This's my code to read file and show content: http://codepen.io/nphunghung/pen/jrbjLQ
This file I using to read: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzvYy1AQW5f-U0FLM2FheVpCOHM

Comment: Regex is not a problem here, JS in not working properly, it just print file into console, did't process it any way